# How to make Character Controller use gravity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]

The screenshot above is the setting of my character, where I used `Character Controller`.

When I play the game, the character just floats in the air instead of standing on the ground.

Could anyone teach me how to make gravity take effect?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer to this question is provided at a following link: [gravity with character controller](https://answers.unity.com/questions/334708/gravity-with-character-controller.html)

What you must do is to modify Move method.

Comment: Could you teach me how to open the `Character Controller`? I cannot find it. I searched and there is no file in my project named `Character Controller`. Thx!

Comment: to find that:
1. select Assets folder in the folders hierarchy.
2. type in the search field "controller" or "character" (try some options if you do not find it).

Comment: Sry but I still cannot find it. I have added the search result in this post, could you point out which is the `Character Controller`? I thought the `ControllerMove` is the one, but it belongs to the PlayMaker plugin.

Comment: Okay, so try it. In the image you can see Character Controller. Click on three dots that belong to Character Controller (upper right corner of Character Controller). Then search for edit option or something like this. If it is not possible maybe this script is unavailable for modification. Weird.